# Как получить определённую цифру из числа?

Tags: swift

К примеру у меня есть число 55674321, мне нужно вытянуть вторую цифру (5). Как это сделать?

Comment: знаю что надо ковырять в сторону char

Comment: Во-первых, это цифра. Во-вторых, скажите, как хранится число - в виде строки или int? Если строка, то да, вынимать один символ, char. Если в виде числа, то другим способом.

Comment: Мимолётно подскажите как читать строкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вот ответ

```
let digits = "0123456789"
let index4 = digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4)
```

**Обновление**

Вот полный ответ на мой же вопрос

```
let digits = KodUser.text!
let index = digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4)
let character = digits[index]
LabelTest.text = String(character)
```